# Разместить div в конце строки (обтекание)

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Как разместить div в конце последней строки текста произвольной длины?
[image: div в конце последней строки текста]

Comment: div { display: inline-block; }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этого задайте внутреннему `div`'у `display:inline-block;` или `display:inline;`:

```css
.block {
  border: #000 solid 2px;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.inner {
  border: #000 solid 2px;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

.inner.inline {
  display: inline;
}

.inner.inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  <div class="inner inline">DIV</div>
</div>
<br /><br />
<div class="block">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
  <div class="inner inline-block">DIV</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй `display: inline;` присвоить к диву